# AWS SNS number of topics limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

There will be number of users. Each users may have number of areas. I want to send email alerts of 3 categories for each area. Each category will have number of email endpoints.

So creating a topic for each category feasible?

for example - if my each area has 3 categories, I'll have to create a topic for each category. so each area will have three tpoics and each topic will have some subscribers.

I want to ask, is this the correct way or are there better options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the scenario, you mentioned, I guess [Filter policy for SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering.html) suits best. You can also follow this AWS tutorial '[Filter Messages Published to Topics](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/filter-messages-published-to-topics/)' for this.

The idea of filter policy is very simple,
When publishing message to topic, you also include some attributes(metadata) in your message for example area=2, category=3
Now this message will be only sent to those subscribers who has this key-value pair mentioned in their subscription policy(attributes) or to all those who don't have any policy at all.

You define subscription policy(attributes), while making subscribe request in your code from client side.

Sample message to publish (Note MessageAttributes in the message):

```
{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "e3c4e17a-819b-5d95-a0e8-b306c25afda0",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111122223333:MySnsTopic",
  "Message" : message body with transaction details . . .
  "Timestamp" : "2017-11-07T23:28:01.631Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : signature . . .
  "UnsubscribeURL" : unsubscribe URL . . .
  "MessageAttributes" : {
    "customer_interests" : {"Type":"String.Array","Value":"[\"soccer\", \"rugby\", \"hockey\"]"},
    "store" : {"Type":"String","Value":"example_corp"},
    "event" : {"Type":"String","Value":"order_placed"},
    "price_usd" : {"Type":"Number","Value":210.75}
  }
}
```

Sample subscriber policy:

```
{
    "store": ["example_corp"],
    "event": [{"anything-but":"order_cancelled"}],
    "customer_interests": ["rugby", "football", "baseball"],
    "price_usd": [{"numeric":[">=", 100]}]
}
```

About Limits:
By default, SNS offers 10 million subscriptions per topic, and 100,000 topics per account.  To request a higher limit, please contact Support. [Link](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/)

I hope this answer puts you in the right direction to now think/move in

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Can we set filter policy at the time of creating subscription i.e. with `subscribe` function?

Comment: You can call setSubscriptionAttributes just after the subscribe call.  
    For java (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSClient.html#setSubscriptionAttributes-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)    for CLI (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/set-subscription-attributes.html)

Comment: Yes. but `setSubscriptionAttributes` needs subscriptionArn, which I'll not have untill and unless user/endpoint call `confirmSubscription`. So considering this situation how am I going to set filter attributes? May I know, am a novice in this.:)

Comment: oh yes! Its good in a way, which will save the calls and configuration for all who won't confirm at all. So call to set subscription attribute will be after confirm-subscription call is made from the client side, which in turn will give you the ARN you are after...

Comment: But how will I know when a user calls confirmSubscription function?

Comment: What I am trying to say is. I'll call subscribe (at this time I know whom to assign what policy) function for 20 users for which I want to set different subscription policy. out of which say 10 confirm it. I can list who all have confirmed but how will I know whom to assign what policy?

Comment: Its all about how you design your workflow. You can store policies temp somewhere. At subscribe call, you can store policy per user with the unique key may be as endpoint like email, in say dynamoDb. Later fetch it back and apply.